# how to host a flex web application on internet?

Tags: apache-flex

Recently I have developed a flex web application and now I wanted to put on internet. I know that there are quite a lot free web hosting company but I am bit confused as in how I have to start. Application which i built used PHP and MySQL database. Currently I am running it on WAMP server.

Could you please let me know how exactly I can host it on internet.

Answer (score 0):

A host like this -> http://www.cfdynamics.com/
Or probably a virtual server or root server at a normal hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

I use Java as a back-end for my Flex web applications and it can communicate smoothly with Flex.

Comment: I have used PHP as back-end.. will there be any problem?